# Why is my SmtpServer.Send code sending multiple copies of emails?

Tags: vb.net

Whenever the send email function is called, recipient will receive three same email at the same time. I have checked through the coding and I could not find what is the cause for such scenario. The email can successfully send out, but I want only one email arrived, not three. Here is the code:

```
Private Sub SendEmail(ByVal item_no As String)
    Dim recipient() As String
    recipient = New String() {"user1@company.com", _
                              "user2@company.com", _
                              "user3@company.com", _
                              "user4@company.com"}

    Dim carboncopy() As String
    carboncopy = New String() {"myuser1@company.com", _
                               "myuser2@company.com", _
                               "myuser3@company.com", _
                               "myuser4@company.com"}

    Dim SmtpServer As New SmtpClient()
    Dim mail As New MailMessage()

    SmtpServer.Credentials = New  _
    Net.NetworkCredential("sender@company.com", "")
    SmtpServer.Port = 25
    SmtpServer.Host = "SmtpServer"

    mail = New MailMessage()
    mail.From = New MailAddress("sender@company.com")

    For i As Integer = 0 To recipient.Length - 1
        mail.To.Add(recipient(i))
    Next

    For i As Integer = 0 To carboncopy.Length - 1
        mail.CC.Add(carboncopy(i))
    Next

    mail.Subject = "Item No. " & item_no

    mail.Body = "Hi" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
    "To Whom May Concern," & vbCrLf & _
    "Please provide the new instruction for item no. " & item_no & "."

    Try
        SmtpServer.Send(mail)
        SmtpServer = Nothing

    Catch ex As Exception
        lblError.Text = ex.ToString
        Exit Sub

    End Try
End sub
```

Comment: See my comment here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8920920/why-is-swiftmailer-sending-two-emails

Comment: By "recipient", do you mean each of the 8 recipients receive three copies, for a total of 24?

Comment: @Brad Sorry,I was unfamiliar with PHP coding,perhaps you can tell me the solution of your problem.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Not 24 email, only 1 email send to each of 4 recipient and CC to another 4 recipient. But now each recipient receive 3 same email at the same time.

Comment: Verify where the SendEmail function is being called - make sure its not being called multiple times. Also, could it be a setting on the mail server that is causing this?

Comment: @SamuelNg If each of the 8 recipients (including the 4 CC's) gets the email 3 times, that means for each email sent, 24 are received. Is that correct? I suspect what's happening is that you're sending the email to 8 destinations, and someone's mail folder just happens to be the target of 3 of those destinations, so they receive three copies.

Comment: There are a few possibilities: Do some of the email addresses route to the same mailbox? Is this an ASP.Net project - perhaps the method is being called multiple times due to page postbacks that are unaccounted-for?